# Use of unassigned local variable

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

While I am trying to debug this code (in C# WinForms), it shows an error

> "use of unassigned local variable" at **'arrlist[i]'**

Since I'm comparing it with a database variable, I cannot initialize the size of the array.

This is the code:

```
if (count != 0)
{
    OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(
        "select seat_no, booking_date, show_time "+
        "from tickets "+
        "where ticket_no = (select max(ticket_no) from tickets)", c);
    OleDbDataReader oledb1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
    oledb1.Read();
    string retr_seats = oledb1.GetString(0);
    char comma = ',';
    string[] strarray = retr_seats.Split(comma);
    int ticket_length = strarray.Length;
    string[] arrlist;
    int i = 0;      
    foreach(var control in this.Controls)
    {
        if(control is Label)
        {           
            arrlist[i] = control.ToString();
            i++;
        }
   }       
   for(var j=0;j<=ticket_length;j++)
   {
       for (var k = 0; k <= i-1; k++)
       {
            if (arrlist[k].Contains(strarray[j]))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(strarray[j]);
            }
       }
   }
}
```

Please help me

Comment: Looks like you could just put `string[] arrList = new arrList[this.Controls.Count]`.

Comment: Actually, why not just have `string[] arrList = this.Controls.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why C# local variables must be initialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182666/why-c-sharp-local-variables-must-be-initialized)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to initialize the variable `arrlist`. Change this line:

```
string[] arrlist;
```

To this:

```
string[] arrlist = new string[this.Controls.Count]; // Must be big enough.
```

---

Or better, use a dynamically sized container such as a `List<string>`.

```
List<string> arrList = new List<string>();
foreach(var control in this.Controls)
{
    if(control is Label)
    {
        arrlist.Add(control.ToString());
    }
}
```

---

Or use LINQ to get the result directly:

```
string[] arrlist = this.Controls
    .OfType<Label>()
    .Select(control => control.ToString())
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: But length is not there. only Count.. any way it works... Thanks for the help!! :)

Comment: @MohanRajK: Thanks for the correction. Please also consider the other options because they are better.

Comment: Do you upvote my question?? I'm in urgent that I want to ask another question with image. But I don't have enough reputation points. Please.. I want one more point

Answer (score 1):

Change your array to a list, and add values to the list.  You can then index the list elements directly, or if you need an array, you can use `.ToArray()` on the list instance.

Also note that your for loop over `j` will go out of bounds on `strarray` unless you change the comparison to `< ticket_length` from `<= ticket_length`.

```
...

var arrlist = new List<string>();

foreach(var control in this.Controls) 
if(control is Label) 
{ 
    arrlist.Add(control.ToString()); 
} 

for(var j=0;j<ticket_length;j++)  
    for (var k = 0; k < arrlist.Count; k++)  
        if (arrlist[k].Contains(strarray[j]))  
             MessageBox.Show(strarray[j]);
```

Answer (score 0):

string[] arrlist;
....
arrlist[i] = control.ToString();

you lost initialization like: arrlist = new string[count];

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that arrlist is defined, but not initialized.

You need to initialize it, like this:

```
string[] arrlist = new arrlist[size];
```

If you don't know how big it will be, it is better to use a list:

```
List<string> arrlist = new List<string>();
```

and to add items: `arrlist.add("some string");`