# Use of unassigned local variable: value type vs custom struct

Tags: c#, struct

A primitive C# value type, for example `int` is a struct. So, why is `int` not initialized? There supposed to be default constructor, I think. On the other hand, a custom struct is ok.

In the following code

```
struct STRCT { }
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        STRCT strct;
        strct.Equals(8);
        strct.GetHashCode();
        strct.GetType();
        strct.ToString();

        int i;
        i.Equals(8);
        i.GetHashCode();
        i.GetType();
        i.ToString();
    }
}
```

while first 5 lines of code are ok from the C# compiler view, next 5 lines of code generates compile error:

> use of unassigned local variable

Please, explain why?  From my point of view both types are structs and shall have the same behavior.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233000/why-compile-error-use-of-unassigned-local-variable#answer-9233045 Please refer above link, it will help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why C# local variables must be initialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182666/why-c-sharp-local-variables-must-be-initialized)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a pathological extreme of the rules of Definite Assignment. Specifically:

> A struct-type variable is considered definitely assigned if each of its instance variables is considered definitely assigned.

In this case (`STRCT strct`), the set of instance variables is empty, and so it is true that they've all been definitely assigned.

Comment: I think the question was why the int is not initialized, not why the struct works

Comment: @ThomasWeller Because the `int` contains a data field that is not initialised, whereas the empty `struct` does not.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: exactly. That should be part of the answer.

Answer (score 5):

This is because, unlike the `int`, your `STRCT` doesn't contain any fields and therefore doesn't contain anything that could be "unassigned".

Try changing it to:

```
struct STRCT
{
    public int X;
}
```

Then you'll get the same compile error:

> Error CS0165  Use of unassigned local variable
>   'strct'   ConsoleApplication1 D:\Test\CS6\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs  15

The C# language specification has explicit rules for "Definite Assignment" in section 5.3:

> At a given location in the executable code of a function member, a variable is said to be definitely assigned if the compiler can prove, by a particular static flow analysis (§5.3.3), that the variable has been automatically initialized or has been the target of at least one assignment

And then:

> A struct-type variable is considered definitely assigned if each of its instance variables is considered definitely assigned.

So from that last rule, if a struct has no instance variables (i.e. fields) then it is considered to be "definitely assigned", and therefore no compile error will be omitted.

Comment: There should, however, be an error saying that the `strct` variable itself is not initialized? Shouldn't there be a `new` line somewhere?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar The parts of the C# specification that I quoted above make it clear why this happens.

Comment: wow! i did not know it! SO, i need do strct.X=5 and its work. Amazing, but IMHO is source of mess

Answer (score 1):

It's **class Members** that are automatically initialized - so if your int was a field or a property in a class, you'd fine.

However, **local variables to a method** are not initialized and expect you to give them a value.

Your struct variable works ok for the time being, since it contains no members of its own. Once you add

```
struct STRCT
{
    private int a;
}
```

you'll get an error for it, too.

Answer (score 0):

`Structs` are `value types`

> Unlike `reference types`, a `value type` cannot contain the null value. However, the nullable types feature does allow for value types to be assigned to null.
>   Each value type has an implicit default constructor that initializes the default value of that type. For information about default values of value types

See - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx

Comment: You should use the > character to indicate quotes. And IMHO your post does not answer the question.