# C# CS0165 on the result of Quaternion

Tags: c#, quaternions, euler-angles

i want to convert my Quaternions in to euler angles but in this function I get an error on result.W. The error is CS0165.

```
public static Quaternion Euler(string[]text)
{
     double yaw = Convert.ToDouble(text[1]);
     double pitch = Convert.ToDouble(text[2]);
     double roll = Convert.ToDouble(text[3]);

     yaw = (Math.PI / 180) * yaw;
     pitch = (Math.PI / 180) * pitch;
     roll = (Math.PI / 180) * roll;

     double yawOver2 = yaw * 0.5f;
     float cosYawOver2 = (float)System.Math.Cos(yawOver2);
     float sinYawOver2 = (float)System.Math.Sin(yawOver2);
     double pitchOver2 = pitch * 0.5f;
     float cosPitchOver2 = (float)System.Math.Cos(pitchOver2);
     float sinPitchOver2 = (float)System.Math.Sin(pitchOver2);
     double rollOver2 = roll * 0.5f;
     float cosRollOver2 = (float)System.Math.Cos(rollOver2);
     float sinRollOver2 = (float)System.Math.Sin(rollOver2);
     Quaternion result;
     result.W = cosYawOver2 * cosPitchOver2 * cosRollOver2 + sinYawOver2 * sinPitchOver2 * sinRollOver2;
     result.X = sinYawOver2 * cosPitchOver2 * cosRollOver2 + cosYawOver2 * sinPitchOver2 * sinRollOver2;
     result.Y = cosYawOver2 * sinPitchOver2 * cosRollOver2 - sinYawOver2 * cosPitchOver2 * sinRollOver2;
     result.Z = cosYawOver2 * cosPitchOver2 * sinRollOver2 - sinYawOver2 * sinPitchOver2 * cosRollOver2;
     return result;

 }
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Use of unassigned local variable 'name'

Comment: Well I would suggest that you need to initialise result as a new Quaternion?

Comment: On which line is the error?

Comment: result.W = cosYawOv..... here in result

Comment: You will find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41802585/9695604). Short version: `Quaternion result = new Quaternion();`

Comment: Please show us your Quaternion definition.

Comment: Quaternion result = new Quaternion(); this one worked. I got one more question. How does the returnvalue looks like? how can i use it. Is it an array ? How do i use these four values?

Comment: It returns 1 Quaternion, you can use it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Use of unassigned local variable 'name':  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0165

You cannot access W because most probably in your Quaternion definition you use properties or some other code that requires explicit object creation.

Comment: Quaternion  is a structure, it cannot be null.